# How to detect all matches for regex in single string in go

Tags: regex, go

I am attempting to build a regex to detect a unix timestamp like pattern in a string.  However, some strings contain multiple "unix time" like patterns and go's regex only detects the first instance of such pattern.

My current regex:

utcRegex, _ := regexp.Compile(`^.*\[(\d{7,})\].*`)

utcCheck := utcRegex.FindStringSubmatch(string)

utc := utcCheck[1]

Here are some example strings:

**Regex works fine with these type of strings**

"Nov  6 11:21:34 [14039] : [1541532094] [DEBUG] FOO BAR"

The regex properly detects the 1541532094

**Regex does not fulfull what I want**

"08-13 11:46:56.379 24980 24980 D SDK: [1565711216] [DEBUG] [15657110953902503] [FOO BAR ]"

The regex only detects 15657110953902503 but not 1565711216. I am only interested in 1565711216. The regex only finds 15657110953902503

Is there an update I can make to my go regex that will detect both of these and then select the first/second instance of this pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is too rigid, try:

```
\[(\d{7,})\]
```

and `$1` will contain the matches.

https://regex101.com/r/XoEx56/1

Comment: I think this is just what I needed. Thanks. regex is like Hieroglyphics sometimes

Comment: Be sure to accept an answer if it solved your question

Comment: @Steve What they said ^^^